# C# string value is not fully shown in VS Code Watch Window

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I have a long json string variable in my C# project. When I try to inspect this variable in **VARIABLES** or **WATCH** - I am only shown the beginning of the string. Rest of the text is hidden.

Even when I try to copy value only the beginning of the text is copied.

What can I do to show the entire value (or at least to copy the entire value)?

Answer (score 1):

In the quickwatch or Watch window, there is an watch icon clicking on which will show the entire value of the variable. You can also choose what type of visualizer to view in.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do not see that stuff.

Comment: The question is about Visual Studio Code, not the original Visual Studio.

Comment: Misread...see below posted answer

Answer (score 1):

My bad...misread the question. Did you try below options:

Option 1:
[image]

Option 2: in Debug console you can type your variable and view the values and copy them as well

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue but I encountered this problem now.

What I do is to goto the "Debug Console" window and then substring on my variable.

Detail instructions:

*In Visual Studio Code, when you are debugging, place a breakpoint on the breaking item.
In my case it is an Exception where I want to know what the message is.*

*Next I open the "Terminal" window (Menu -> View -> Terminal).*

*If you type `ex.Message` and enter, then you get only the first 100 characters.
Visual Studio Code is not showing anything more (just three dots).*

*Then I input in my Terminal `ex.Message.Substring(100)`. I get the next 100 characters of my message.*

*If still I do not have the complete message then I type `ex.Message.Substring(200)`. I get the next 100 characters.*

*and so on until I see my complete message.*

This is the way how I was able to get my complete message. I did the same for the StackTrace.
I didn't find anything else to resolve this or a way to make sure Visual Studio is showing the complete message.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community Bot, I edited it and hope this is more clear. Can't explain it better then this.